# What machine learning method can I use to identify a color?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am a beginner in machine learning and I was wondering what feature can I use to identify the color of a chess piece (black and white).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not actually a machine learning problem. You can use opencv and binarization (threshold) function. Threshold function will set all the pixels that are darker then specified value (127 in the line below) to black and all the lighter pixels to white. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) is the official documentation/tutorial.

```
import cv2
ret,thresh1 = cv.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

For determining the color, you can loop over the pixels and see if pixel is black or white. If there is more black pixels it's black piece, if there is more white pixels, its white piece. If the pixel value is `255` it's white, if it's `0` it's black.

Comment: Can I do it like this? img = cv2.Threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you!

Comment: But will it also get the black chess piece if its in the black empty tile?

Comment: That is a separate case. I cannot answer you without seeing the data. I answered the question you asked, for anything more, I'd have to see the data